# Why am I losing data even though I clearly stored it in a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, asp.net-core, razor-pages

**Screenshots below for clarification**
Using razor pages I have a page called Products which displays a product; image, name, price etc. These details obtained in my get method using an id passed from the previous page.

I initialize a property called Product of type *Product* to the object returned by the method to obtain a product. However, when `OnPost()` method is called the only the Id of the product in the object survives (and I know it's because Id is passed as the parameter and is thus readily available) every other single piece of data is lost. I can't understand why, thanks in advance.

### Product

```
public class ProductModel : PageModel
{
    public string Identity { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    private readonly IShopService _shopService;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public ProductModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IShopService shopService)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _shopService = shopService;
    }
    private Task<IdentityUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    public void OnGet(int id, string identity)
    {
        Product = _shopService.GetProduct(id);
        Identity = identity;
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        _shopService.AddProductToBag(Product, GetCurrentUserAsync().Result);
    }
}
```

[image: Product object during <code>OnGet()</code>]

The screenshot above is a representation of `Product` after `GetProduct()` executes. It is populated by the db data. When I try and use the same data for `AddProductToBag` in `OnPost()` every field is null.

Comment: Please show us the payload being POSTed, from Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab).

Comment: I never send an entire object over web, only Id's as I can always use those to get the objects from the db, the screenshot shown is `Product` after `_shopService.GetProduct(id);` executes. It is not passed over the web, I store the object within the application to be used for the `AddProductToBag()`  in `OnPost()`. Do you still want me to show payload? @mjwills

Comment: The `OnGet` is called on a different web request to the `OnPost`. You need to pass the data from the browser to the server. **Or** call `GetProduct` in the `OnPost`.

Comment: thanks that helps! @mjwills